# Hacer que los pseudoelementos : before :after sean responsivos

Tags: css3

No se como hacer para que los elementos :before(en este caso "<") y after(en este caso "/>" sean responsivos. Me gustaría que a la vez que agrando la pantalla se mantuviese fijos al lado del texto. El problema que al darle un top, left etc queda bien en la pantalla que lo miras pero a la minima que haces la pantalla más ancha no conservan su posición.
No se si hay alguna forma de hacer que se queden fijos o de hacer que vayan creciendo con el texto.
Muchas gracias.
Un saludo!

[image: Imagen]

```
<section class="section__quienes-somos">
<div class="section__quienes-somos-general">
    <div class="section__quienes-somos-parte">
        <h4 class="section__quienes-somos-parte-h4">mundo dance</h4>
        <p class="section__quienes-somos-parte-p">para vosotros</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section__quienes-somos-parte">
        <div class="section__quienes-somos-parte2">
            <p class="section__quienes-somos-parte-p2">quienes somos</p>
            <p class="section__quienes-somos-parte-p3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
                Quas non laudantium voluptatum aspernatur
                magnam libero possimus, et veritatis corporis eligendi deserunt ea iure soluta nemo culpa at
                illum.</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.section__quienes-somos{
    height: 425px;
    position: relative;
}

.section__quienes-somos-general{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height: 85%;
    
}
.section__quienes-somos-parte{
    line-height: 1.4;
    background-color: rgb(24, 23, 23);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
.section__quienes-somos-parte:last-child{
    height: 360px;
    padding: 0!important;
    
}


.section__quienes-somos-parte-h4{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform:  uppercase;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    
}

.section__quienes-somos-parte-h4:before{
    content: "<";
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display:block;
    color: rgb(0, 161, 201);
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 35px;
    left: 10%;
    bottom:10%;

}
.section__quienes-somos-parte-h4:after{
    content: "/>";
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display:block;
    color: rgb(0, 161, 201);
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 35px;
    right: 10%;
    top:50%;

}
```